# Using the class="store_product_price" with sale items?

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to still show that an item is on sale while using the dynamic product variable for store_product_price?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
{if on_sale}{regular_price}{sale_price}{if:else}{price}{/if}
```

When I use the above code, it ONLY shows the sale price, but I'd still like it to show the regular price crossed out.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
{if on_sale}
  Price: <del>{regular_price}</del> 
  {price}.
{if:else}
   Price: {price}
{/if}
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to use the dynamic price variables you would need to do something slightly different in this case then putting the css class on the `h2` element. Something along the lines of this to only show the regular price if the item is on sale.

```
<h2> 
  Price: {if on_sale}<del>{regular_price}</del>{/if} 
  <span class="store_product_price">{price}</span>.   
</h2>
```

Comment: Hi Justin. That is what I am doing now, but it **only** shows the sale price, never the regular crossed out.

Here is exactly what I have in my template...

`<h2 class="store_product_price">
 {if on_sale}Price: <del>{regular_price}</del> {price}. {if:else} Price: {price} {/if}
</h2>`

Comment: Aww sorry I somehow missed the you were using the dynamic variables (rereading the initial question I am not quite sure how I did that. The short answer is if you want to show both sale and regular price you can't use the dynamic variable.

Comment: The content that you enter inside of whatever element you put as the dynamic variable is a fallback when CSS/JS are disabled and under most circumstances won't be displayed to the user.

Comment: Is there a work around? I'd still like the price to dynamically update AND show that the items in on sale. Thx Justin.

Comment: The only work around that I know of at the moment would be to use something similar to the code under Edit 1 or for you to extend the store js to also handle sale price.